# How do I do an order by when a group by is part of the SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I have this SQL:

```
 Select Substring([English],1,1) Col1,
 convert(varchar,Count(1)) Col2
 From Phrase Group by Substring([English], 1, 1)
```

Is there a way I can order this by the value of Substring([English], 1, 1) ?

Comment: Adding to the answers given: you can of course simply add `ORDER BY Substring([English], 1, 1)` - a mere copy and paste, one word changed.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring `varchar` without (length) - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the order by after the group by.

Note you can use aliases from the select in the order by, but not in the group by; as group by executes before the select, and order by executes after the select.

```
 SELECT Substring([English],1,1) Col1
      , convert(varchar,Count(1)) Col2
 FROM Phrase 
 GROUP BY Substring([English], 1, 1)
 ORDER BY COL1
```

Comment: @DVT yes, Updated made.

Answer (score 1):

Order by occurs after the column calculation, you can use the column alias

```
    Select Substring([English],1,1) Col1,
     convert(varchar,Count(1)) Col2
     From Phrase 
    Group by Substring([English], 1, 1)
    Order By Col1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `order by` with column alias.

```
 Select Substring([English],1,1) Col1,
 convert(varchar,Count(1)) Col2
 From Phrase Group by Substring([English], 1, 1)
 order by Col1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Col1, Col2 FROM
( Select Substring([English],1,1) Col1,
 convert(varchar,Count(1)) Col2
 From Phrase Group by Substring([English], 1, 1)
) as Table1
Order By Col1
```

Comment: There is no need in subquery - just add `order by` to the end of statement and refer computed column aliases.